# Is it possible to use non-recursive CSS selectors with the Ruby Nokogiri gem?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

If I have HTML like this:

```
<div id="target">
    <div id="a1">
        <div class="1">
    </div>
    <div id="a2">
        <div class="2">
        <div class="3">
        <div class="4">
    </div>
    <div id="b1">
        <div class="1">
    </div>
    <div id="b2">
        <div class="2">
        <div class="3">
        <div class="4">
    </div>
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

...is it possible to select only the first level of div elements from `target`. So, if I run `page.css('#target div').each` then I get every single div inside `target`. If I just want the results to contain the divs with ids ['a1','a2','b1','b2'] is that possible with Nokogiri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is called a [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

```
#target > div
```

Without the `>` you have a descendant selector, which doesn't care if it's a child, grandchild, great grandchild etc.

Comment: I suspect I should have known this already, I've been working with CSS for a good while now. Anyway, now I do. Thanks!